# Method addWhereExpression does not consider fields without values

Tags: 8, database

Tell me how to create the correct query. 
In its own handler filter for views, a $this->query->addWhereExpression query is created, where the fields in the nodes are selected. If all the fields are fill, then the filter works, that is, the request is handled correctly, but if some fields are not filled, then the filter ignores these nodes.
Example

```
    <?php
$definition = [
                        'table' => 'taxonomy_term__field_kurs',
                        'field' => 'entity_id',
                        'left_table' => 'node__field_currency',
                        'left_field' => 'field_currency_target_id',
                        'operator' => '='
                    ];
                    $join = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.views.join')->createInstance('standard', $definition);
                    $this->query->addRelationship('taxonomy_term__field_kurs', $join, 'node__field_currency');

    $snippet_min = '(node__field_price.field_price_value * taxonomy_term__field_kurs.field_kurs_value * (100 - node__field_discount.field_discount_value)/100 >= '.$min;
    $this->query->addWhereExpression($this->options['group'], $snippet_min);
    ?>
```

That is, if the node node__field_discount.field_discount_value field is empty, it does not exist in the database, and the filter does not display the node. How to make a condition to work.